# How to send form contents anonymously via email

Tags: email, forms

How do you send the content of a website form to an email address without disclosing the email address to the user.

Thanks!

PS: If at all possible, I would like this to be in <s>HTML</s> <s>JavaScript</s> Ok, anything I guess.

Comment: Warning: you can't send mails using HTML.

Comment: You're trying to hide the from address?  Why?  That's a classic spam tactic.

Comment: @Matthew, I think he wants to conceal the *destination* address, not the *source* address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. You can however put a "fake" `from` header in the mail. You'll only risk it to end up in the junk folder.

HTML doesn't provide any functionality to send mails. You'll really need to do this in the server side. How exactly to do this depends on the server side programming language in question. In PHP for example, you have the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. In Java you have the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/). And so on.

Regardless of the language used, you'll need a SMTP server as well. It's the one responsible for actually sending the mail. You can use the one from your ISP or a public email provider (Gmail, Yahoo, etc), but you'll be forced to use your account name in the `from` header. You can also register a domain with a mailbox and just register something like `noreply@example.com` and use this to send mails from.

**Update**: JavaScript can't send mails as well. Like HTML it's a client side language. You'll need to do it with a *server side* language. All JavaScript can do is to dump the entire page content back to the server side. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) may be useful in this:

```
$.post('/your-server-side-script-url', { body: $('body').html(); });
```

with (PHP targeted example)

```
$to = 'to@example.com';
$subject = 'Page contents';
$body = $_POST['body']
$headers = prepare_mail_headers();
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

**Update 2:** if you actually want to hide the `to` header in the mail, then you'll need to use the `bcc` ([Blind Carbon Copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy)) instead. This way the *recipient* addres(ses) will be undisclosed. Only the `from`, `to`, `cc` stays visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean doing so on a client side, using `mailto:` link - you can not.

If you mean any way, yes - you submit the form contents back to your server, and have your back end script send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the form in HTML, but the posting will need to be done in a script.   Even if you don't expose the email address, the script can be used to spam that email address.  This is why you see captcha being used in such cases.
There are scripts available for most languages.  Check to make sure their are no known security problems for the scripts.  The original Matt's script in perl had problems, and the Perl community created a more secure version.